# how to change the jquery date-picker css for the unclickable date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery date-picker and i want that the days list which i am putting in **beforeShowDay** function should get a different colour and also not been able to be selected or clickable....below is some code

i have google this problem a lot....i found half solution of my problem...it changes its colour for those special dates but are clickable but i want them to be **unselected**

```
<style type="text/css">
    td.specialDay, table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.specialDay  a { 
    background: none !important;
    background-color: #fffac2 !important; 
    color: black;
     }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var unavailableDates = ["30-7-2012","11-7-2012","15-8-2012"];
    function unavailable(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"","Book Now"];
      } else {
        return [true,"specialDay","Booked"];
      }
    }

    $(function() {

             $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

                    minDate: 0, 
                    maxDate: "+3M +10D",
                    beforeShowDay: unavailable 

                });

              });

    </script>
```

if there is any solution please tell me...
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me...hope that who are having this kind of problem help them too

below in my answer i have higlighted 3 points so according to that

in step 1 and 2 add this css
in 3rd step edit or copy paste like this

hope that anybody looking this kind of problem will get there answer..if not then tell me ..if i can explain more

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ui-state-active  {      //1.add this
    background: blue !important;
}
.ui-state-active .ui-state-default{   //2. add this
    background: red !important;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var unavailableDates = ["30-7-2012","11-7-2012","15-8-2012"];
    function unavailable(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"","Book Now"];
      } else {
        return [false,"ui-state-active","booked"]; //3. edit here like this..
      }
    }

    $(function() {

             $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

                    minDate: 0, 
                    maxDate: "+3M +10D",
                    beforeShowDay: unavailable 

                });

              });

    </script>
```

Comment: This is not a correct way to do. You have problem on dmy variable. Please put an alert in the "dmy". you may find

Comment: i was having problem on setting of specific dates background to somecolour....and else all working fine...didn't understand what u r saying :|

Answer (score 0):

In else condition you need to mention false to make not select able like

```
if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"","Book Now"];
      } else {
        return [false,"specialDay","Booked"];
      }
```

I found your problem. Please check the dmy variable. and the code which is working fine is

```
 var unavailableDates = ["30-7-2012","11-7-2012","15-8-2012"];
    function unavailable(date) {
     var year, month, day, currDate;
     year = String(date.getFullYear());
     month = String(date.getMonth() + 1);
    if (month.length === 1) {
         month = "0" + month;
    }
    day = String(date.getDate());
     if (day.length === 1) {
         day = "0" + day;
     }
      dmy = String(day+'-'+month+'-'+year);
      if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"","Book Now"];
      } else {
        return [false,"specialDay","Booked"];
      }
    }
```

Hope this may helps

Comment: i have already tried that but...then it will do the unclickable but the colour wont change means then that specialDay class don't work

Comment: try to override the css like .unavailable-day span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E07272 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

Comment: could you check whether the  special day has the html structure is similar to

<td title="Booked" class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled specialDay">
<span class="ui-state-default">10</span></td>

Comment: It s working fine for me. Could you check with firebug? whether the class is applied or not if not means try to override and return false for the "Booked"

Answer (score 0):

you have problem on checking the dates in an array. Please Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MYVMw/2/) which is working fine and the correct way to do. I hope it may useful for you

Comment: i don't have problem in checking the dates...i was having problem that..i can change the css of that particular dates..but i want them not to be selected...so i want the date to be marked in different colour and that too with unselectable.......i don't why u keep saying that there is a problem in dmy...i have taken that refernce from a accepted answer...and is working very welll